# Javascript - Regular Expression to match a number long 5 digits

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a JS file that is already connected to my HTML template. And I have an input form which I want it only accept Numbers 0-9, with an exact number of characters of 5 numbers. 
So I placed the function:

```
function validate (input) {
  if($(input).attr('type') == 'text' || $(input).attr('name') == 'text') {
  if($(input).val().trim().match(/^[0-9].{5}/) == null) {
    return false;
  }
 }
```

Now the input cannot proceed with entered number, tried letters, numbers, less than 11 character and more than 5 but it still returns an error.

When I use this one, it accepts numbers only, doesn't accept less than 5 characters, but it can accept more than 5 which I don't want.

```
function validate (input) {
  if($(input).attr('type') == 'text' || $(input).attr('name') == 'text') {
  if($(input).val().trim().match(/^[0-9]{5}/) == null) {
    return false;
  }
 }
```

Please help me editing this match `match(/^[0-9]{5}/)` to make it:

- Accept only numbers
- Accept only and exact number of characters (5 characters only)

Comment: `/^\d{5}$/.test(yourValue)`

Comment: Thank you for that.. It worked ! .. But why you didn't put your answer as answer rather than comment.. So I could choose it as Best Answer.

Comment: It is so trivial that I didn't bother writing up an answer for that. Use `.test` instead of `.match` if you are not matching anything, ie you don't care about the substring it matched.

Comment: `.test` is the best solution, use the right function rather than bending another one to do as you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `/^[/\d]{5}?$/` to match only digits and the exact number of digits is 5.

```js
function validate (input) {
  return input.match(/^[/\d]{5}?$/) !== null      
}

console.log(validate('12345'))
console.log(validate('1234444'))
console.log(validate('1223a'))
console.log(validate('1234'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No need for the explicit conditional, just return the bool from this expression: `return input.match(/^[/\d]{5}?$/) !== null`

Answer (score 2):

```
var match = $(input).val().trim().match(/[0-9]{5}/);

return match !== null && match[0] === match.input;
```